# throwing NoHandlerFoundException and configuring custom 404 page in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception

I have been learning Spring for just 7 months. While I used spring MVC only, i want to configure custom 404 page by throwing NoHandlerFoundException or enabling it in the dispatcher servlet. Now, i am learning spring boot, can anyone explain to me?

Comment: Why not try the old way as in Spring? It should work in Boot, and I was suggested to hand exception that way.

Comment: In Spring i used to catch the 404 not found expection by setting the thorwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound to true in the dispatcherServlet.xml. But in boot i can't figure out a way to catch the 404 not found exception properly. Does @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) also catch the 404not found exception?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, got it resolved. Below given steps to solve the same.

1. Create a class `GlobalExceptionHandler` annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler 
{
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public String handleNotFoundError(Exception ex) 
    {
        return "redirect:/yourCustom404page";
    }
}
```

2. By default, when a page/resource does not exist the servlet container will render a default 404 page. If you want a custom 404 response then you need to tell `DispatcherServlet` to throw the exception if no handler is found. We can do this by setting the `throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound` servlet initialization parameter to `true`

to achieve this

a. In spring-boot
`spring.resources.add-mappings=false` in your application.properties or yaml file.

b. If spring-mvc java based configuration is

```java
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
    ...

    @Override
    protected DispatcherServlet createDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext servletAppContext) 
    {
        final DispatcherServlet servlet = (DispatcherServlet) super.createDispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);
        servlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        return servlet;
    }

}
```

c. if spring-mvc xml based configuration, initialize your dispatcher servlet like this

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```